# Scrape all amenities and Calendar data from AirBnB

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I manage to scrape a lot of information from AirBnB but i have to questions.

This is my code for scraping several information such as price, rating etc.

Imports

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests, re
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
```

Main code

```
url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Thessaloniki--Greece/homes?tab_id=home_tab&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&place_id=ChIJ7eAoFPQ4qBQRqXTVuBXnugk&query=Thessaloniki%2C%20Greece&date_picker_type=calendar&search_type=user_map_move&price_filter_input_type=0&ne_lat=40.66256734970964&ne_lng=23.003752862853986&sw_lat=40.59051931897441&sw_lng=22.892087137145978&zoom=13&search_by_map=true&federated_search_session_id=1ed21e1c-0c5e-4529-ab84-267361eac02b&pagination_search=true&items_offset={offset}&section_offset=2'


data = []
for offset in range(0,40,20):
    driver.get(url.format(offset=offset))
    time.sleep(2)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')


    detailed_pages = []
    for card in soup.select('div[class="c4mnd7m dir dir-ltr"]'):
        link = 'https://www.airbnb.com' + card.select_one('a[class="ln2bl2p dir dir-ltr"]')['href']
        detailed_pages.append(link)

        
    for page in detailed_pages:
        driver.get(page)
        time.sleep(3)
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        room_type = soup2.select_one('div._tqmy57')
        room_type =  room_type.text if room_type else None
        r= requests.get(page)
        p_lat = re.compile(r'"lat":([-0-9.]+),')
        p_lng = re.compile(r'"lng":([-0-9.]+),')
        lat = p_lat.findall(r.text)[0]
        lng = p_lng.findall(r.text)[0]
        room_id = page[29: link.index("?")]
        titles = soup2.select_one('span._1n81at5')
        titles = titles.text if titles else None
        price = soup2.select_one('span._tyxjp1')
        price = price.text if price else None
        rating= soup2.select_one('span._12si43g')
        rating = rating.text if rating else None
        Bedroom_area = soup2.select_one('div[class="_1a5glfg"]')
        Bedroom_area = Bedroom_area.text if Bedroom_area else None
        place_offers= ', '.join([x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup2.select('[class="sewcpu6 dir dir-ltr"]+div:nth-of-type(3) > div')])
        data.append({
            'Room_ID':room_id,
            'titles':titles,
            'place_offers': place_offers,
            'price':price,
            'rating':rating,
            'Bedroom_area': Bedroom_area,
            'Room_Type': room_type,
            'Latitude':lat,
            'Longitude':lng
        })

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

1. The first question is how can I click on buttons like amenities, description etc. and scrape them, since in the landing page we just have some information about this but not all the info.

I know that there is a function `.click()` in sellenium but i am trying the following code:
`soup2.select_one('div.b6xigss dir dir-ltr').click()`
but I am getting that error:  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'` .

2. The second question is how can I scrape the calendar data and which dates are blocked or not ?

Comment: try to remove the space from your CSS selector, `soup2.select_one('div.b6xigss.dir.dir-ltr').click()`  this should work if you are selecting the correct tag. Also, it'll help if you share the link to the page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: The link is this one `https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/37857422?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-10-30&check_out=2022-11-04&federated_search_id=bcf69359-a1b0-4c4d-b251-a9892a067a68&source_impression_id=p3_1662410214_T2S54CxrpOUOxCN6`. Also without space is not working. Maybe my tag is wrong.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I don't see `soup2.select_one('div.b6xigss dir dir-ltr').click()`  in your code. Better show code which makes problem.

Comment: `.click()` works only with `driver.find_element(...)` (`Selenium`) but not with `soup2.select_one(...)` (`BeautifulSoup`)

Comment: some pages may use `lazy loading` and they may add elements when user scroll down - and it may need to use selenium and `execute_script()` to run `JavaScript` which will scroll page.

Comment: I can find this element using only `div.b6xigss` (`driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.b6xigss button').click()`) but there is message about cookies and it can't click it. It would need to clik message about cookies and later click button. OR it would need to use JavaScript (`execute_script()`) to click this button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scrape data from multiple urls on airbnb with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73595042/how-to-scrape-data-from-multiple-urls-on-airbnb-with-python) Answer contains also handling of amenities.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems:

- `click()` works only with `Selenium` (`driver.find_element()`) but not with `BeautifulSoup` (`soup2.select_one()`) - so first you have to use different function
- for some reasons it can't find `'div.b6xigss.dir.dir-ltr'` but it finds `'div.b6xigss button'` (To make sure I search `button` because `div` can be `"unclickable"`)
- there is message about cookies and it hides this element and selenium can't click. It would need to close this message (accept cookies), or it would need to scroll page to move button in visible place, or it needs to use `JavaScript` (`driver.execute_script()`) to click it.

This works for me

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.b6xigss button')

driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button)
```

---

Miniamal working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://www.airbnb.com/s/Thessaloniki--Greece/homes?tab_id=home_tab&flexible_trip_lengths%5B%5D=one_week&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&place_id=ChIJ7eAoFPQ4qBQRqXTVuBXnugk&query=Thessaloniki%2C%20Greece&date_picker_type=calendar&search_type=user_map_move&price_filter_input_type=0&ne_lat=40.66256734970964&ne_lng=23.003752862853986&sw_lat=40.59051931897441&sw_lng=22.892087137145978&zoom=13&search_by_map=true&federated_search_session_id=1ed21e1c-0c5e-4529-ab84-267361eac02b&pagination_search=true&items_offset={offset}&section_offset=2'

p_lat = re.compile(r'"lat":([-0-9.]+),')
p_lng = re.compile(r'"lng":([-0-9.]+),')

data = []

for offset in range(0, 40, 20):
    print('offset:', offset)
    
    driver.get(url.format(offset=offset))
    time.sleep(2)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    detailed_pages = []
    
    for card in soup.select('div[class="c4mnd7m dir dir-ltr"] a[class="ln2bl2p dir dir-ltr"]'):
        link = 'https://www.airbnb.com' + card['href']
        detailed_pages.append(link)
        
    print('len(detailed_pages):', len(detailed_pages))
    
    for number, page in enumerate(detailed_pages, 1):
        print(number, 'page:', page)

        driver.get(page)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        
        room_type = soup2.select_one('div._tqmy57')
        room_type = room_type.text if room_type else None
        
        #r= requests.get(page).text
        r = driver.page_source
        
        lat = p_lat.findall(r)[0]
        lng = p_lng.findall(r)[0]
        
        room_id = page[29: link.index("?")]
        
        titles = soup2.select_one('span._1n81at5')
        titles = titles.text if titles else None
        
        price = soup2.select_one('span._tyxjp1')
        price = price.text if price else None
        
        rating= soup2.select_one('span._12si43g')
        rating = rating.text if rating else None
        
        bedroom_area = soup2.select_one('div[class="_1a5glfg"]')
        bedroom_area = bedroom_area.text if bedroom_area else None
        
        place_offers= ', '.join([x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup2.select('[class="sewcpu6 dir dir-ltr"]+div:nth-of-type(3) > div')])
        
        try:
            button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.b6xigss button')
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', button)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)
                                              
        data.append({
            'Room_ID': room_id,
            'titles': titles,
            'place_offers': place_offers,
            'price': price,
            'rating': rating,
            'Bedroom_area': bedroom_area,
            'Room_Type': room_type,
            'Latitude': lat,
            'Longitude': lng
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As for calendar: every date has `aria-disabled=True` or `aria-disabled=False` and you can use `aria-disabled` to detect dates in calendar and later you can get value from `aria-disabled` like from any other attribute - `item["aria-disabled"]`

---

**EDIT:**

This works for me

```
for number, page in enumerate(detailed_pages, 1):

    print(number, 'page:', page)

    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(5)

    # ... other code ...

    xpath = '//div[@aria-label="Calendar"]//div[@data-testid]'
    
    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath):
        date    = item.get_attribute("data-testid")
        blocked = item.get_attribute("data-is-day-blocked")
        print(blocked, '|', date)
```

Result like this:

```
true | calendar-day-09/18/2022
true | calendar-day-09/19/2022
true | calendar-day-09/20/2022
false | calendar-day-09/21/2022
false | calendar-day-09/22/2022
false | calendar-day-09/23/2022
```

Comment: But how can i extract them also in a list ?

Comment: I don't understand you. Create empty list before `for`-loop and use `.append()` inside `for`-loop to add then to this list.

Comment: I mean for the amenities, when I try to open directly the link with the amenities open I can find the amenities by this `a= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"_11jhslp")
for i in a:
    print(i.text)` but when I execute your code this return me an empty list and i cannnot understand why :/ .

Comment: I manage to do it with this code `amenities = [i.text.split('\n')[0] for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[data-testid="modal-container"] [id$="-row-title"]')))] `

Comment: did you run code in correct place ? Inside `for number, page in enumerate(detailed_pages, 1):` ? If you run it for main page then it will not find any calendar. You have to run it for page with details. I will add `for number, page in enumerate(detailed_pages, 1):` to answer.

Comment: Yes i was referring to amenities not to the calendar :)